# Convergence of series over full modular group

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question regarding the series over the full modular group $\Gamma=\{\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)\mid a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Z, ad-bc=1\}$
$$R_n(z):=\sum_{\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)\in\Gamma}(az+b)^{-n-1}(cz+d)^{-(w-n)-1}$$
for $w\in\mathbb{N}$ even and $0<n<w$. This functions (up to a constant) were defined in [Modular Forms with Rational Periods](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/scanned/ModFormsRatPeriods/fulltext.pdf) by Kohnen and Zagier on p. 204. My question would be, why this series is uniformly absolutely convergent (hence why we can change the sum and the integral). They argue that
$$\sum_{ad-bc=1}(a^2+b^2)^{-n-1}(c^2+d^2)^{-(w-n)-1}$$
converges (which I also don't quite understand) and therefore $R_n(z)$ converges for sets of the form $y^2\ge c_1+c_2x^2 (c_1, c_2>0)$. Why does this mean, that $R_n(z)$ converges?

Comment: For $n>1, w-n > 1$ the convergence is easy.

Comment: Maybe you could give me a hint. And what about the other cases?